# mapping one model to two tables in nHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

These are my tables:

```
Object {
  ID,
  col1,
  col2
}

ObjectExtra {
  ID,
  objectID,
  col3
}
```

and this is my mapping class:

```
ObjectMapping {

    Map(x => x.prop1).Column("col1")
    Map(x => x.prop2).Column("col2")

    Join("ObjectExtra", join =>
    {
       join.KeyColumn("objectID");
       join.Map(x => x.prop3).Column("col3")
    });
}
```

my problem is every time i query on Object class, nHibernate joins **Object** table with **ObjectExtra** table. but i want nHibernate to join these tables when i select columns from **ObjectExtra** table, not when i select columns only from **Object** table.

how can i make joins dynamically?